# Storing loop output in a dataframe in R for each iteration

Tags: r

What I am wanting to do is to store and combine the output of veh.velocity into a new dataframe y for each iteration. I understand it is best to first set up an empty dataframe and then combine the columns of data at the end. Different iterations also have a different amount of rows. It is possible to just consider the first 20? Very sorry if there are several issues and misconceptions below, I only started programming a few months ago. Thanks

CSV File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tMOz_yM-WenSOlF3UK6UatniwtFI7kzf/view?usp=sharing

```
#Time series
#This programme evaluates each vehicles speed behaviour w.r.t time. 

library(ggplot2)
library(fpc)
library(factoextra)
library(readr)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(fpp2)

#Clear all variables in workspace
rm(list=ls())

#Importing data
df <- read_csv("01_tracks.csv")

#Preparing data 
df1 <- filter(df,laneId == 5, width <= 6) #Filtering to only lane 5 and no trucks

#Creating empty lists
y <- data.frame()

#Loop to plot time series for only filtered vehicle id's
for(i in unique(df1$id)[1:6]) { #Only considering first 6 vehicles for now due to long computation time
  print(i) #List of vehicle id's
  veh <- filter(df1,id == i) #New dataframe for vehicles/id's which are in lanes 5
  timeseries <- ts(veh[,7],start = 1) #Declare as time series data
  plot(autoplot(timeseries) + ggtitle(i) + ylab("X Velocity")) #Plotting time series
  veh.velocity <- select(veh,xVelocity) #New dataframe for only vehicle id and its velocity 
  y <- cbind.data.frame(y,veh.velocity)
}
```

Comment: I get an error trying to access your csv file.  Have you given the correct access rights?  Gnerally speaking, if you're using a `for` loop in R, there's a better way of doing things.  (There are exceptions, but not here, I suspect.)  My preferred apporach would be to make your data [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) and then use `group_by` to process each vehicle.  Failing that, I would use `lapply` to process each vehicle and then `bind_rows` to join the results.  Also, consider separating data preparation from results presentation.

Comment: I wouldn't think plotting in a loop is good idea, that would be too much unnessary plot for most cases.
If you want to do some tranformation on your data, `mutate` and `transmute` would be better choice for most cases. It's rarely the case creating empty data.frame is needed. Also, `purrr::map_dfr` could be quite helpful in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to plot a time series of the individual vehicle IDs, I'm not sure there's a reason to use a loop. For example, you could easily make a `time` variable and plot with `ggplot2`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(time = 1:n()) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = time, y = xVelocity, color = as.factor(id))) +
  geom_line(show.legend = FALSE, alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

And you could use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr` to reshape the data:

```
library(tidyr)
result <- df1 %>% 
            group_by(id) %>%
            mutate(time = 1:n()) %>%
            dplyr::select(time, xVelocity) %>% 
            pivot_wider(id_cols = time, values_from = xVelocity,
                        names_prefix = "Veh.", names_from = id)
result
# A tibble: 414 x 287
    time Veh.1 Veh.3 Veh.7 Veh.11 Veh.12 Veh.14 Veh.15 Veh.25 Veh.31 Veh.47 Veh.50 Veh.53 Veh.55 Veh.59
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1  40.8  35.7  32.6   24.7   35.8   41.5   35.7   37.9   39.2   39.2   40.3   39.5   33.0   38.2
 2     2  40.9  35.7  32.6   24.8   35.8   41.5   35.7   37.9   39.2   39.2   40.3   39.5   33.0   38.2
 3     3  40.9  35.7  32.6   24.8   35.8   41.5   35.7   38.0   39.2   39.2   40.3   39.6   33.0   38.2
 4     4  40.9  35.7  32.6   24.8   35.8   41.5   35.7   38.0   39.2   39.2   40.3   39.6   33.1   38.2
 5     5  40.9  35.7  32.6   24.8   35.8   41.5   35.7   38.0   39.2   39.2   40.3   39.6   33.1   38.1
 6     6  40.9  35.7  32.6   24.9   35.8   41.6   35.7   38     39.2   39.2   40.4   39.6   33.1   38.1
 7     7  40.9  35.7  32.7   24.9   35.8   41.6   35.7   38.0   39.2   39.2   40.4   39.6   33.1   38.1
 8     8  40.9  35.7  32.7   24.9   35.8   41.6   35.7   38.0   39.2   39.3   40.4   39.6   33.1   38.1
 9     9  41.0  35.8  32.7   25.0   35.8   41.6   35.7   38.0   39.2   39.3   40.4   39.6   33.1   38.1
10    10  41.0  35.8  32.7   25     35.8   41.6   35.7   38.1   39.2   39.3   40.4   39.7   33.1   38.1
# … with 404 more rows, and 272 more variables:
```